# glVertexAttribPointer - vertex normal or color

Tags: c++, opengl

When I use glVertexAttribPointer how OpenGL knows if I refer to vertex, normal or color? Here is my piece of code:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), 0);
```

On that example I refer to vertex. Buy how does OpenGL knows it? If I want to add normal to my shape, How does I tell to OpenGL that this is normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't.

*You* specify to the GL, either through inline location attribute in the shader or through binding with [glBindAttribLocation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) which location will be used with your input shader attributes.

Syntax for the location in shader (a [layout qualifier](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29)):

```
layout(location = attribute index) in vec3 position;
```

Edit to add: I should mention that if you don't specify a location, the GL will choose on its own, and you then have to ask which locations it used through [glGetAttribLocation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml).